# I just deleted /etc/rc?.d/ dirs, how can I restore/recreate them?

Tags: debian, restore, linux

`sysv-rc` was installed to get a hold of systems autostart, but in the end it wasn't needed (as update-rc.d came in handy). So I dumbly do `apt-get purge sysv-rc` and type `Yes, do as I say!` to the apt prompt and bam! - no dirs/files in `/etc/rc?.d`

What can/should I do? I believe I don't have full backup for this server.

And I also tried doing i.e.  `update-rc.d mysql defaults` but it seems it only edits `/etc/runlevel.conf` and doesn't involve direct actions with `etc/rc?.d/` :(

**edit:** can anyone also help out with the link on how `/etc/rc?.d/` is generated? If I still have `/etc/runlevel.conf`, is there any chance `/etc/rc?.d/` dirs/simlinks will be recreated automatically after system reboot? Thanks.

Comment: See also: http://serverfault.com/questions/133505/rebuilding-etc-rc-d-links

Comment: Have you tried installing sysv-rc back? And then try rebuilding using `insserv /etc/init.d` or something similar

Comment: @jscott thanks, seen that though. Problem is I in no way can remember the order of process' start/stop.

Comment: @ptman I installed `sysv-rc` and `sysv-rc-conf` back and it seems it generated all `/etc/rc?.d/` dirs with proper symlinks to `init.d` scripts! Thanks so much. Do you mind making this a proper answer to my question so I could vote it?

Comment: Don't ever type "Yes, do as I say!" because merely _seeing_ that prompt means you are about to break your system. While you got lucky here, you probably will not be so lucky next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reinstall the purged package (sysv-rc). If that isn't enough, try to recreate the links using `insserv /etc/init.d` or something similar.